# Error when running android emulator

Tags: java, android

I get this on Logcat when I try to test my app on the emulator but it runs perfectly on desktop mode. I am using Eclipse, Android SDK, and LIBGDX. I don't know why it doesn't want to run. This is the Logcat information I get when the emulator doesn't run the app.

```
09-03 01:09:24.940: D/dalvikvm(762): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
09-03 01:09:28.020: D/dalvikvm(762): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.kovach.flappytimberman.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb1d30748
09-03 01:09:28.060: D/dalvikvm(762): Added shared lib /data/app-  lib/com.kovach.flappytimberman.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb1d30748
09-03 01:09:28.060: D/dalvikvm(762): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.kovach.flappytimberman.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb1d30748, skipping init
09-03 01:09:28.170: D/(762): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7741878, tid 762
09-03 01:09:28.860: I/AndroidInput(762): sensor listener setup
09-03 01:09:29.130: W/EGL_emulation(762): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-03 01:09:29.180: D/OpenGLRenderer(762): Enabling debug mode 0
09-03 01:09:29.290: D/(762): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb782e448, tid 776
09-03 01:09:29.320: W/GL2JNIView(762): creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context
09-03 01:09:29.410: D/dalvikvm(762): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.kovach.flappytimberman.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb1d30748
09-03 01:09:29.420: D/dalvikvm(762): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.kovach.flappytimberman.android-1/libgdx.so' already loaded in same CL 0xb1d30748
09-03 01:09:29.420: I/GL2(762): all initialized 2
09-03 01:09:29.420: I/AndroidGraphics(762): OGL renderer: Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (GeForce GT 740M/PCIe/SSE2)
09-03 01:09:29.420: I/AndroidGraphics(762): OGL vendor: Google (NVIDIA Corporation)
09-03 01:09:29.420: I/AndroidGraphics(762): OGL version: OpenGL ES 2.0 (4.4.0)
09-03 01:09:29.420: I/AndroidGraphics(762): OGL extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float 
09-03 01:09:29.460: E/EGL_emulation(762): [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
09-03 01:09:29.460: E/EGL_emulation(762): tid 776: eglGetConfigAttrib(607): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
09-03 01:09:29.470: E/EGL_emulation(762): [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
09-03 01:09:29.470: E/EGL_emulation(762): tid 776: eglGetConfigAttrib(607): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
09-03 01:09:29.540: I/AndroidGraphics(762): framebuffer: (5, 6, 5, 0)
09-03 01:09:29.540: I/AndroidGraphics(762): depthbuffer: (24)
09-03 01:09:29.550: I/AndroidGraphics(762): stencilbuffer: (0)
09-03 01:09:29.550: I/AndroidGraphics(762): samples: (0)
09-03 01:09:29.550: I/AndroidGraphics(762): coverage sampling: (false)
09-03 01:09:29.610: I/AndroidGraphics(762): Managed meshes/app: { }
09-03 01:09:29.610: I/AndroidGraphics(762): Managed textures/app: { }
09-03 01:09:29.620: I/AndroidGraphics(762): Managed shaders/app: { }
09-03 01:09:29.620: I/AndroidGraphics(762): Managed buffers/app: { }
09-03 01:10:11.200: D/dalvikvm(889): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.kovach.flappytimberman.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb1d299d8
09-03 01:10:11.250: D/dalvikvm(889): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.kovach.flappytimberman.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb1d299d8
09-03 01:10:11.250: D/dalvikvm(889): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.kovach.flappytimberman.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb1d299d8, skipping init
09-03 01:10:11.350: D/(889): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7741378, tid 889
09-03 01:10:11.810: I/AndroidInput(889): sensor listener setup
09-03 01:10:12.480: W/EGL_emulation(889): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-03 01:10:12.530: D/OpenGLRenderer(889): Enabling debug mode 0
09-03 01:10:12.860: D/(889): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7810f30, tid 902
09-03 01:10:12.880: I/Choreographer(889): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-03 01:10:12.890: W/GL2JNIView(889): creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context
09-03 01:10:12.950: D/dalvikvm(889): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.kovach.flappytimberman.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb1d299d8
09-03 01:10:12.950: D/dalvikvm(889): Shared lib '/data/app-lib/com.kovach.flappytimberman.android-1/libgdx.so' already loaded in same CL 0xb1d299d8
09-03 01:10:12.970: I/GL2(889): all initialized 2
09-03 01:10:12.970: I/AndroidGraphics(889): OGL renderer: Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (GeForce GT 740M/PCIe/SSE2)
09-03 01:10:12.990: I/AndroidGraphics(889): OGL vendor: Google (NVIDIA Corporation)
09-03 01:10:12.990: I/AndroidGraphics(889): OGL version: OpenGL ES 2.0 (4.4.0)
09-03 01:10:13.000: I/AndroidGraphics(889): OGL extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_vertex_half_float 
09-03 01:10:13.000: E/EGL_emulation(889): [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
09-03 01:10:13.000: E/EGL_emulation(889): tid 902: eglGetConfigAttrib(607): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
09-03 01:10:13.000: E/EGL_emulation(889): [getAttribValue] Bad attribute idx
09-03 01:10:13.000: E/EGL_emulation(889): tid 902: eglGetConfigAttrib(607): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
09-03 01:10:13.000: I/AndroidGraphics(889): framebuffer: (5, 6, 5, 0)
09-03 01:10:13.000: I/AndroidGraphics(889): depthbuffer: (24)
09-03 01:10:13.000: I/AndroidGraphics(889): stencilbuffer: (0)
09-03 01:10:13.000: I/AndroidGraphics(889): samples: (0)
09-03 01:10:13.000: I/AndroidGraphics(889): coverage sampling: (false)
09-03 01:10:13.020: I/AndroidGraphics(889): Managed meshes/app: { }
09-03 01:10:13.020: I/AndroidGraphics(889): Managed textures/app: { }
09-03 01:10:13.080: I/AndroidGraphics(889): Managed shaders/app: { }
09-03 01:10:13.090: I/AndroidGraphics(889): Managed buffers/app: { }
09-03 01:10:14.450: D/dalvikvm(889): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 359K, 18% free 2291K/2788K, paused 44ms, total 45ms
09-03 01:10:14.830: I/dalvikvm(889): Failed resolving Lcom/kovach/TweenAccessors/SpriteAccessor; interface 96 'Laurelienribon/tweenengine/TweenAccessor;'
09-03 01:10:14.830: W/dalvikvm(889): Link of class 'Lcom/kovach/TweenAccessors/SpriteAccessor;' failed
09-03 01:10:14.840: E/dalvikvm(889): Could not find class 'com.kovach.TweenAccessors.SpriteAccessor', referenced from method com.kovach.screens.SplashScreen.setupTween
09-03 01:10:14.840: W/dalvikvm(889): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1172 (Lcom/kovach/TweenAccessors/SpriteAccessor;) in Lcom/kovach/screens/SplashScreen;
09-03 01:10:14.850: D/dalvikvm(889): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0003
09-03 01:10:14.860: I/dalvikvm(889): Could not find method aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenManager.update, referenced from method com.kovach.screens.SplashScreen.render
09-03 01:10:14.860: W/dalvikvm(889): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 349: Laurelienribon/tweenengine/TweenManager;.update (F)V
09-03 01:10:14.870: D/dalvikvm(889): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
09-03 01:10:14.870: I/dalvikvm(889): Failed resolving Lcom/kovach/TweenAccessors/SpriteAccessor; interface 96 'Laurelienribon/tweenengine/TweenAccessor;'
09-03 01:10:14.870: W/dalvikvm(889): Link of class 'Lcom/kovach/TweenAccessors/SpriteAccessor;' failed
09-03 01:10:14.870: D/dalvikvm(889): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x3317 at 0x05 in Lcom/kovach/screens/SplashScreen;.setupTween
09-03 01:10:14.870: D/dalvikvm(889): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x015c at 0x0d in Lcom/kovach/screens/SplashScreen;.setupTween
09-03 01:10:14.900: I/dalvikvm(889): Failed resolving Lcom/kovach/screens/SplashScreen$1; interface 97 'Laurelienribon/tweenengine/TweenCallback;'
09-03 01:10:14.900: W/dalvikvm(889): Link of class 'Lcom/kovach/screens/SplashScreen$1;' failed
09-03 01:10:14.910: D/dalvikvm(889): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x33a6 at 0x14 in Lcom/kovach/screens/SplashScreen;.setupTween
09-03 01:10:14.930: W/dalvikvm(889): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1af6d70)
09-03 01:10:14.940: E/AndroidRuntime(889): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 78
09-03 01:10:14.940: E/AndroidRuntime(889): Process: com.kovach.flappytimberman.android, PID: 889
09-03 01:10:14.940: E/AndroidRuntime(889): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kovach.TweenAccessors.SpriteAccessor
09-03 01:10:14.940: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.kovach.screens.SplashScreen.setupTween(SplashScreen.java:50)
09-03 01:10:14.940: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.kovach.screens.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:45)
09-03 01:10:14.940: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
09-03 01:10:14.940: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.kovach.flappytimberman.FlappyTimberman.create(FlappyTimberman.java:20)
09-03 01:10:14.940: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:236)
09-03 01:10:14.940: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1512)
09-03 01:10:14.940: E/AndroidRuntime(889):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
09-03 01:10:15.070: I/AndroidInput(889): sensor listener tear down
09-03 01:10:15.070: I/AndroidGraphics(889): Managed meshes/app: { }
09-03 01:10:15.070: I/AndroidGraphics(889): Managed textures/app: { }
09-03 01:10:15.080: I/AndroidGraphics(889): Managed shaders/app: { }
09-03 01:10:15.080: I/AndroidGraphics(889): Managed buffers/app: { }
09-03 01:10:19.400: I/Process(889): Sending signal. PID: 889 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `com.kovach.TweenAccessors.SpriteAccessor` is there any class with this name in your project?

Comment: Yes there is just looking at it now exactly the same name.